# How to initialize global in Play 2.0 application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

The Global object in Play 2.0 application would not be initialized until the first time a page of the app is loaded for the first time.

I can think of a hack to retrieve a page of the app when the app is deployed/started/restarted but I am looking for a cleaner way.

How can I make sure the Global object initialization would not wait until the first page load?

Comment: Possibly it just occurs when you running app in development mode (run command)?
For me it works with "sbt start" ("play start") as well as I started it on the server in production mode.

Comment: did you overrides the onStart() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to reply by [viktornk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830928/viktortnk), this only happens in development mode when running "play run". If 
 you start the application in production mode by "sbt start" or "play start" it initializes immediately. Hopefully, this would also happen when you build and application and deploy into container.